# Atribuir conteúdo Json à variável PHP

Tags: php, json, rest

Salve galera,
Estou iniciando no mundo WebService e já me deparo com o seguinte problema.

O Servidor da TOTVS via rest, me retorna exatamente da seguinte forma:

```
$resposta = enviaConteudoParaAPI($cabecalho, $conteudo, $url, $tpRequisicao);
print_r($resposta);
```

Resultado:

```
{"CAMPOS":"[\"\"A1_COD\",\"A1_NOME\",\"TIPO\"]","DADOS":"[[\"00932221\",\"PEDRO GONCALVES\",\"TITULAR\"][\"00164577\",\"JORGE ARAGAO\",\"TITULAR\"]]"}

//TRATADO
$array = json_decode($resposta, true);
    $campos = $array['CAMPOS'];
    $dados = $array['DADOS'];
    print_r($array);
```

Resultado:

```
Array ( [CAMPOS] => [""A1_COD","A1_NOME","TIPO"] [DADOS] => [["00932221","PEDRO GONCALVES","TITULAR"]["00164577","JORGE ARAGAO","TITULAR"]] )
```

Acontece que preciso atribuir cada conteúdo a uma variável, ou seja, preciso trabalhar com cada valor de forma distinta:

```
    $A1_COD = ['$A1_COD'];
    $A1_NOME = ['A1_NOME'];
    $TIPO = ['TIPO'];
echo "Codigo: $A1_COD, Nome: $A1_NOME, Tipo: $TIPO";
```

Onde eu preciso do seguinte resultado:

```
Codigo: 00932221 , Nome: PEDRO GONCALVES, Tipo: TITULAR
Codigo: 00164577 , Nome: JORGE ARAGAO,    Tipo: TITULAR
```

Em outras palavras, preciso transformar este array:

```
 Array ([["00932221","PEDRO GONÇALVES","TITULAR"]["00164577","JORGE ARAGAO","TITULAR"]])
```

Neste array:

```
Array ( [A1_COD] => 00932221 [A1_NOME] => PEDRO GONÇALVES [TIPO] => TITULAR ) 
Array ( [A1_COD] => 00164577 [A1_NOME] => JORGE ARAGAO [TIPO] => TITULAR )
```

SOLUÇÃO:

Solicitei correção na resposta do servidor, que estava retornando com aspas a mais, retorno valido:

```
$jsonString = '{
    "CAMPOS": ["A1_COD", "A1_NOME", "TIPO"],
    "DADOS": [
        ["33436681", "MARCOS ALAN", "REPRESENTANTE"],
        ["34007644", "MARCOS ALBERTO", "TITULAR"],
        ["67762840", "MARCOS ALVES", "TITULAR"],
        ["55178561", "MARCOS ANTONIO", "TITULAR"]
    ]
}';

$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);

foreach ($array['DADOS'] as $dados) {
    $novoArray[] = array_combine($array['CAMPOS'], $dados); 
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($novoArray);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [A1_COD] => 33436681
            [A1_NOME] => MARCOS ALAN
            [TIPO] => REPRESENTANTE
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [A1_COD] => 34007644
            [A1_NOME] => MARCOS ALBERTO
            [TIPO] => TITULAR
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [A1_COD] => 67762840
            [A1_NOME] => MARCOS ALVES
            [TIPO] => TITULAR
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [A1_COD] => 55178561
            [A1_NOME] => MARCOS ANTONIO
            [TIPO] => TITULAR
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu acho que no seu caso você pode usar o `list`.

```
list($a1_cod, $a1_nome, $tipo) = $retorno['CAMPOS']
```

O `list` pegará cada índice (começando do `0` e atribuirá na sequência em que os valores estão dispostos dentro de `CAMPOS`.

Você poderia acessar esses índices também através do número:

```
 echo $retorno['CAMPOS']['A1_COD']
```

Apesar de não estar muito claro na pergunta, me parece que você deseja combinar `CAMPOS` com `DADOS`.

Se for, para fazer isso, você pode combinar `array_map` e `array_combine`.

```
$retorno = [

    'CAMPOS' => [ 'A1_COD','A1_NOME','TIPO'],
    'DADOS' => [
        ["00932221","PEDRO GONCALVES","TITULAR"],
        ["00164577","JORGE ARAGAO","TITULAR"]
    ]
];


$valores_combinados = array_map(function ($dados) use($retorno) {
    return array_combine($retorno['CAMPOS'], $dados);
}, $retorno['DADOS']);


print_r($valores_combinados);
```

O Resultado é:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [A1_COD] => 00932221
            [A1_NOME] => PEDRO GONCALVES
            [TIPO] => TITULAR
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [A1_COD] => 00164577
            [A1_NOME] => JORGE ARAGAO
            [TIPO] => TITULAR
        )

)
```

Acima poderia ser percorrido com `foreach`.

```
foreach($valores_combinados as $valor) {
       echo $valor['A1_COD'];
}
```

Veja funcionando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/8JxqzQ)

Comment: Wallace, vou tentar ser mais detalhista.

Comment: Se for fazer alguma consideração, edite sua pergunta e adicione detalhes, mas já adianto que você não deveria deixar alguém responder sua pergunta para depois dizer com clareza o que precisa.

Comment: Wallace, editei minha duvida, ve se ficou mais claro.

Comment: @MarcosSantos mas a resposta faz exatamente o que você quer. Você testou a solução que eu coloquei?

Comment: testei, mas não compilou.

Comment: Como assim "não compilou"? PHP é uma linguagem interpretada.

Comment: Não rodou pois o php não está aceitando o array atribuído a variável $retorno como um array válido, logo, nada é retornado.

Comment: @MarcosSantos e qual é a mensagem de erro especifica?

Comment: Guilherme, bom dia. Não da nem erro, simplesmente a pagina fica em branco.

Comment: Wallace, bom dia!
Cara, sua solução está certinha, o que estava errada era o retorno que estava recebendo do servidor, estava com aspas a mais.
Muito obrigado pelo apoio.